# C: float changing to 'nan' value

Tags: c

I have an inner function in a larger program that is somehow changing a float value to "nan" when I expect it to be zero.  I have trimmed the function down to the simplest form, with no parameters:

```
static void func(void)
{
    int a = 1;
    float x = 0.0f;
    float v = 0.0f;
    printf("x(%f), ", x);
    x += (float)a * v;
    printf("x(%f), ", x);
    printf("(int)x: %d, ", (int)x);
}
```

This gives the output:

```
x(0.000000), x(nan), (int)x: -2147483648
```

If I remove the variable `a` and hardcode the value (1), the nan value goes away.  Similarly, if I remove the line `x += (float)a * v;`, everything prints as expected (all zeroes).

The frustrating part is that I can't reproduce this by just creating a new program and tossing this in `main()`.  When I try that, the program works perfectly and outputs:

```
x(0.000000), x(0.000000), (int)x: 0
```

---

Disassembly from the function in the actual program:

```
00000029 <_func>:
  29: 55                    push   %ebp
  2a: 89 e5                 mov    %esp,%ebp
  2c: 83 ec 38              sub    $0x38,%esp
  2f: c7 45 f4 01 00 00 00  movl   $0x1,-0xc(%ebp)
  36: a1 18 00 00 00        mov    0x18,%eax
  3b: 89 45 f0              mov    %eax,-0x10(%ebp)
  3e: a1 18 00 00 00        mov    0x18,%eax
  43: 89 45 ec              mov    %eax,-0x14(%ebp)
  46: d9 45 f0              flds   -0x10(%ebp)
  49: dd 5c 24 04           fstpl  0x4(%esp)
  4d: c7 04 24 00 00 00 00  movl   $0x0,(%esp)
  54: e8 a7 ff ff ff        call   0 <_printf>
  59: d9 45 f0              flds   -0x10(%ebp)
  5c: db 45 f4              fildl  -0xc(%ebp)
  5f: d9 5d e4              fstps  -0x1c(%ebp)
  62: d9 45 e4              flds   -0x1c(%ebp)
  65: d9 45 ec              flds   -0x14(%ebp)
  68: de c9                 fmulp  %st,%st(1)
  6a: de c1                 faddp  %st,%st(1)
  6c: d9 5d f0              fstps  -0x10(%ebp)
  6f: d9 45 f0              flds   -0x10(%ebp)
  72: dd 5c 24 04           fstpl  0x4(%esp)
  76: c7 04 24 00 00 00 00  movl   $0x0,(%esp)
  7d: e8 7e ff ff ff        call   0 <_printf>
  82: d9 45 f0              flds   -0x10(%ebp)
  85: d9 7d e2              fnstcw -0x1e(%ebp)
  88: 0f b7 45 e2           movzwl -0x1e(%ebp),%eax
  8c: b4 0c                 mov    $0xc,%ah
  8e: 66 89 45 e0           mov    %ax,-0x20(%ebp)
  92: d9 6d e0              fldcw  -0x20(%ebp)
  95: db 5d dc              fistpl -0x24(%ebp)
  98: d9 6d e2              fldcw  -0x1e(%ebp)
  9b: 8b 45 dc              mov    -0x24(%ebp),%eax
  9e: 89 44 24 04           mov    %eax,0x4(%esp)
  a2: c7 04 24 08 00 00 00  movl   $0x8,(%esp)
  a9: e8 52 ff ff ff        call   0 <_printf>
  ae: c9                    leave  
  af: c3                    ret
```

Disassembly from stand-alone function (as `main()`):

```
00000000 <_main>:
   0:   55                      push   %ebp
   1:   89 e5                   mov    %esp,%ebp
   3:   83 e4 f0                and    $0xfffffff0,%esp
   6:   83 ec 30                sub    $0x30,%esp
   9:   e8 00 00 00 00          call   e <_main+0xe>
   e:   c7 44 24 2c 01 00 00    movl   $0x1,0x2c(%esp)
  15:   00 
  16:   a1 18 00 00 00          mov    0x18,%eax
  1b:   89 44 24 28             mov    %eax,0x28(%esp)
  1f:   a1 18 00 00 00          mov    0x18,%eax
  24:   89 44 24 24             mov    %eax,0x24(%esp)
  28:   d9 44 24 28             flds   0x28(%esp)
  2c:   dd 5c 24 04             fstpl  0x4(%esp)
  30:   c7 04 24 00 00 00 00    movl   $0x0,(%esp)
  37:   e8 00 00 00 00          call   3c <_main+0x3c>
  3c:   db 44 24 2c             fildl  0x2c(%esp)
  40:   d8 4c 24 24             fmuls  0x24(%esp)
  44:   d9 44 24 28             flds   0x28(%esp)
  48:   de c1                   faddp  %st,%st(1)
  4a:   d9 5c 24 28             fstps  0x28(%esp)
  4e:   d9 44 24 28             flds   0x28(%esp)
  52:   dd 5c 24 04             fstpl  0x4(%esp)
  56:   c7 04 24 00 00 00 00    movl   $0x0,(%esp)
  5d:   e8 00 00 00 00          call   62 <_main+0x62>
  62:   d9 44 24 28             flds   0x28(%esp)
  66:   d9 7c 24 1e             fnstcw 0x1e(%esp)
  6a:   0f b7 44 24 1e          movzwl 0x1e(%esp),%eax
  6f:   b4 0c                   mov    $0xc,%ah
  71:   66 89 44 24 1c          mov    %ax,0x1c(%esp)
  76:   d9 6c 24 1c             fldcw  0x1c(%esp)
  7a:   db 5c 24 18             fistpl 0x18(%esp)
  7e:   d9 6c 24 1e             fldcw  0x1e(%esp)
  82:   8b 44 24 18             mov    0x18(%esp),%eax
  86:   89 44 24 04             mov    %eax,0x4(%esp)
  8a:   c7 04 24 08 00 00 00    movl   $0x8,(%esp)
  91:   e8 00 00 00 00          call   96 <_main+0x96>
  96:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
  9b:   c9                      leave  
  9c:   c3                      ret    
  9d:   90                      nop
  9e:   90                      nop
  9f:   90                      nop
```

Comment: @iharob the function is reproducing the issue when run in the full program

Comment: Using `"%e"` or `"%a"` rather than `"%f"` will provide more information.

Comment: Same problem, it should be reproducible within your sample code, if it occurs in your program and not in another program, then something is wrong with your program and not with this function.

Comment: Is `#include <stdio.h>` used before `func(void)`?

Comment: @chux yes, stdio.h is included, and both %e and %a print "nan" as well

Comment: @iharob yes...clearly there is something different in the context of the program.  The rest of the program is huge - that's why I tried to simplify the question to the specific function at issue.  Perhaps a better question would be "why would this small, self-contained function produce this issue in the context of a larger program?"

Comment: *I have trimmed the function* does the trimmed function also shows the issue in your program?

Comment: @ouah I'm not sure what you mean - what/where is the trimmed function?

Comment: Does this happen always when the function is called or just sometimes? I can imagine something like this happening when the stack is nearly overflowing (or the stack of a nearby thread) or the stack was smashed previously. If you're using gcc or clang, try compiling the program that shows the error with `-fsanitize=address` and see if that finds anything, and the other `-fsanitize=` options are worth a try as well.

Comment: @EldenAbob the trimmed function is the function you pasted right below your sentence *I have trimmed the function*

Comment: @ouah I didn't realize you were quoting - I thought you meant you had trimmed the function yourself.  Yes - the trimmed version does exhibit the issue.

Comment: @EldenAbob in that case please post a complete, minimal and compilable test case with your system and compiler version information.

Comment: @Wintermute I suspected as much, and I have tried both Valgrind and -fsanitize=address, neither have reported anything.

Comment: Suspect compiler bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is often the result of undefined behavior.  In this specific instance, there was an implicit function declaration (a header file hadn't been included elsewhere in the program) which caused UB, and resulted in this bug.